# No output from requests.get()

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-requests-html

I am using the requests library to output contents of a corporate confluence page.

I've run the program with non-corporate test confluence page, like [this](https://confluence.atlassian.com/questionstest/test-page-938641191.html), and I was able to get the correct output. I've tried running with and without credentials for my corporate confluence page. I've checked the URL and page ID and was able to view the JSON data on my browser. I'm working on a linux VM.

```
def get_page_json(page_id, expand = False):
    if expand:
        suffix = "?expand=" + expand
    else:
        suffix = ""
    url="https://confluence.CORP_URL_HERE/rest/api/content/" + page_id + suffix
    response = requests.get(url, auth=(user, password))
    return(response.text)

def main():
    print(get_page_json("PAGE_ID_HERE", "body.storage"))
```

When I run the code with authentication, I get no output or errors. I ran status_code and I got `200`. When I ran my code without the authentication, I got `status_code` `404`.

Let me know if I am overlooking anything, it may completely be an error on part of the confluence being a corporate page.

Comment: For clarity, the corp site only uses HTTP?

Comment: If the data is sent back in json, you should look at the json output, not the text. Try `response.json()`.

Comment: Could you also give information about your Python and Requests versions?

Comment: if `r.text` is empty, `r.json()` will be empty as well

Comment: `return` is not a function

Comment: what are response headers?

Comment: I have the latest version of requests, 2.22 and python 3.7.3. When I run response.json() I actually get error - ```json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)```.

Comment: @ladygremlin thank you for your comment, I checked and it seems that the corp confluence is not using HTTP. Does anyone have suggestions to using another protocol or method to access the corp confluence?

Comment: @lin If it doesn't use HTTP, try and log on yourself and give the info in headers that you'd provide. It's like single-sign on, OAuth, or something more complicated than basic auth. :)